# O uso da vírgula em sentença explicativa ou predicado

Tags: sintaxe, vírgula

O uso da vírgula é justificável nas situações abaixo?

*"A porta conta com um sistema de travamento por amortecedor hidráulico, para garantir a sua abertura mesmo em condições desfavoráveis."*

*"A Figura mostra os módulos constituintes do equipamento, abrigados dentro do gabinete."*

Sei que as orações separadas pelas vírgulas tem o intuito de apresentar uma explicação ou informação adicional, mas não seriam parte do predicado?

Answer (score 1):

A vírgula pode separar o predicado de si mesmo, especialmente com advérbios. Vide:

> Eu gostei de jogar vôlei contigo, ontem.

Portanto, não há inerentemente problema em fazê-lo com essas frases, as quais se tratam de um sistema `Oração Principal + Oração Subordinada`.

**Na primeira:**

> "A porta conta com um sistema de travamento por amortecedor hidráulico, para garantir a sua abertura mesmo em condições desfavoráveis."

`[A porta... hidráulico,]` é a *oração principal (OP)* da frase, `[para... desfavoráveis.]` é a *oração subordinada adverbial final reduzida de infinitivo (OSAFRI)*. A subordinada pode ser desenvolvida para `... hidráulico, para que garanta a sua abertura mesmo...`, uma simples *OSAF*.

Por a subordinada ser uma justificativa ao fato de que a porta contém um sistema de travamento por amortecedor hidráulico, pode ser separada da oração sem perda semântica — leia a frase sem a vírgula e perceberá.

**Na segunda:**

> "A Figura mostra os módulos constituintes do equipamento, abrigados dentro do gabinete."

`[A Figura... equipamento,]` é a *OP* da frase, `[abrigados dentro do gabinete.]` é a [*oração subordinada adjetiva explicativa*](https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/sint/sint36.php) [*reduzida de particípio*](https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/sint/sint45.php) *(OSAERP)*. A subordinada pode ser desenvolvida para `... equipamento, os quais se abrigam dentro do gabinete.`, uma simples *OSAE*.

Por a subordinada adicionar informação (sobre a localização) sobre os módulos e estar precedida de vírgula, depreende-se que é uma oração explicativa — em detrimento da restritiva (vide link) —, a qual, em raciocínio circular, pede separação da *OP* por vírgula.

**Conclusão**:

A vírgula na primeira frase é opcional, porém é aconselhável por tornar o texto melhor organizado, mesmo estando no mesmo predicado; na segunda frase, é obrigatória por normas gramaticais.