# Ambiguidade na língua falada entre uma restritiva e uma explicativa

Tags: pronúncia, sintaxe, ambiguidades

[Esta pergunta em Portuguese.StackExchange](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/5261/o-uso-da-v%C3%ADrgula-em-senten%C3%A7a-explicativa-ou-predicado) me inspirou a levantar uma dúvida que carrego comigo há muito tempo.

Por exemplo, a sentença:

> Adoro aquela garota, que é sempre muito prestativa.

é diferente de:

> Adoro aquela garota que é sempre muito prestativa.

**A primeira:** gosta-se de uma garota, e diz-se que ela é muito prestativa. Ser muito prestativa pode estar relacionado ao apreço por ela ou não, porém gosta-se dela, e é prestativa. Uma oração principal + oração subordinada adjetiva explicativa.

**A segunda:** dentre todas as garotas, gosto daquela em específico salientada do grupo por sua característica de prestatividade. Uma oração principal + oração subordinada adjetiva restritiva.

---

Em texto, a diferença faz-se explícita. Todavia, por não ser possível "falar vírgula", na línguagem dita não há distinção clara entre ambas. (pausa no discurso não significa nada)

Existe uma maneira de, em língua proferida, transmitir essas duas ideias diferentes sem perda semântica?

Comment: Mas a vírgula, nesse caso, não corresponderia a uma pausa na fala? De qualquer forma, ficaria mais claro com um "e ela" no lugar do "que" na primeira sentença.

Comment: Não, a vírgula é marcadora de OSAExplicativa. Novamente, pausa na fala não explicita o sentido desejado pelo interlocutor, já que não é um recurso linguístico per se, é apenas algo que ocorre na comunicação falada — seja para respirar, pensar, suspense, seja o que for, pausa não evidencia diferença gramatical.

Comment: Porém, sim, substituir o 'que' por 'ela' seria uma opção, mas há alteração semântica porquanto o '...garota, ela é sempre...', sugere que o motivo do apreço é a prestatividade, enquanto que isso não ocorre na construção com OSAExplicativa.

Comment: Veja que a substituição que mencionei é por "**e** ela", mas concordo que a ambiguidade (sobre a prestatividade ser ou não a razão do apreço) nesse caso também não é preservada, porque com o "e" fica claro que se trata apenas de uma informação extra.

Comment: Agora, "pausa no discurso não significa nada" não me parece correto. Eu diria que a pausa é um recurso expressivo - pode ser usado, por exemplo, para ênfase.

Comment: Não concordo que uma pausa na fala não explicita sentidos. E não sei o que você entende por recurso linguístico....a pausa é uma característica da fala que pode transmitir sentido ou não. Acho que falando ninguém diria: "Adoro aquela garota que é sempre muito prestativa." Seria ultra-culto ou esnobe. "Adoro aquele tipo de garota que é sempre prestativa". Devo dizer que a frase 1) e a frase 2) são registros bem diferentes....

Comment: @stafusa De fato, pausa dá ênfase, porém ênfase não adiciona significado, apenas realça um pré-existente, portanto ainda não significa nada. Entretanto, mesmo que suponhamos que signifique, não substitui palavras. Se formos distinguir dois sentidos diferente na língua falada por meio de pausa, no cotidiano inúmeros mal entendidos poderiam ocorrer (mal entendido em uma construção sem ambiguidade, puramente escrita, só poderia surgir a partir da interpretação de texto), pois não há parâmetro para o que define uma 'pausa' e simplesmente o espaço de tempo entre a pronúncia de palavra subsequentes.

Comment: Portanto, pausa não configura um elemento para transmitir sentidos. *Eu adoro [pausa...] aquela garota* -> pode haver um sentimento adicional quando a frase é pronunciada dessa forma, porém o significado dela é o mesmo, independente de possíveis interpretações subjetivas.
Quanto a @Lambie, "Adoro aquela... prestativa" é o suprassumo da ordinariedade na língua escrita e falada; em realidade, é o padrão para expressar essa ideia no português (outras estruturas são alternativas), não concebo por que seria esnobe. Em relação ao resto, não entendi.

Comment: @WilliamLio, Penso que esses mal entendidos acontecem mesmo, e só não ocorrem com mais frequência por conta do contexto. E eu diria que a pausa, exercendo em alguns casos um papel que é o da vírgula na linguagem escrita, pode sim alterar significados. Por exemplo, as frases: i) "Não, estamos em casa." e ii) "Não estamos em casa." tem significados opostos que, oralmente, seriam tipicamente distinguidos por uma pausa após o "não".

Comment: @stafusa Nessa construção, realmente, porém nesse caso ainda há a questão da intonação. Na [i] o 'Não' é pronunciado como fim de frase, enquanto que existe continuidade na intonação da [ii], portanto não apenas a pausa influencia isso; mais uma vez, a última não é utilitário explícito da comunicação pois não é o único que marca a diferença. Ademais, o contexto nessas mesmas frases ainda é importante, na medida em que o primeiro é uma pergunta de sim ou não, a resposta dada é não, e informa-se a verdadeira localização do respondente; enquanto que a segunda é resposta a "Estão em casa?".

Comment: Não concordo que a intonação determine tão fortemente o sentido quanto a pausa. Outro exemplo, com mais contexto:   
"Eu te incomodo?"    
Após encará-la em silêncio por alguns segundos, ele admite, em tom neutro:   
i) "Não, gosto de você."    
ii) "Não gosto de você."

Comment: Contexto, em muitas situações, é tudo.  Se eu digo "Adoro aquela garota, que é sempre muito prestativa",  é óbvio que eu já identifiquei quem é aquela garota anteriormente.  Ou então estou apontando para ela.

Comment: @stafusa   Dizer "Não, gosto de você" é gostar da ambiguidade.  A fim de evitá-la, qualquer um diria "Não, **eu** gosto de você".

Comment: @stafusa Pausa e intonação em todos esses casos estão inerentemente relacionados. De qualquer forma, a questão inicial permanece. (OBS: se pararmos para pensar, proferir o "Não, gosto de você." no exato mesmo tom em que a [ii] (existem diversas formas de tom neutro) soa suspeito a mim, pelo menos, quanto aos verdadeiros sentimentos da pessoa falando. No final, pausas, intonações, ênfases, não dão a mesma segurança que a palavra.)

Comment: @Centaurus Não qualquer um - pode talvez até ser a opção mais provável, mas não é a única. Eu, em particular, com frequência prefiro omitir o pronome quando possível. A pontuação mais adequada no exemplo, no entanto, provavelmente seria com ponto, e não vírgula, mas isso não é relevante.

Comment: @WilliamLio Estou deixando a discussão. Um abraço.

Comment: Agradeço a participação.

Comment: Vou recomeçar: Embora as frases sejam diferentes pela diferença de sentido introduzido pela vírgula, elas não são do mesmo registro. Uma é linguagem formal e a outra é uma frase ordinária que todo mundo diria. A segunda frase é um português litérario e formal. Em geral fulano diz algo como: Adoro as garotas (que são) prestativas. E não usaria o singular para identificar uma tipo de garota.....na minha opinião. Parece Proust falando português. :)

Comment: @Lambie Não parece, ambas as estruturas são tão comuns que a questão da formalidade mal se aplica a elas, são ubíquas independente do contexto social-profissional; qualquer falante nativo de pt (seguramente pt-br pelo menos) confirmará.

Comment: Não concordo. Mas me canço, sabe? Sou interpréte de português e conheço os "níveis de língua" como falamos na minha profissão. As frases têm nível diferente. Mas, tudo bem. Deixemos o assunto.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77149/discussion-on-question-by-william-lio-ambiguidade-na-lingua-falada-entre-uma-res).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na fala as orações adjetivas restritivas e explicativas distinguem-se pela entoação. A restritiva juntamente com o termo a que se refere (*aquela garota que é sempre muito prestativa*) constitui, nas palavras dum artigo que cito abaixo, “uma frase entonacional”. Pelo contrário, a explicativa (*que é sempre muito prestativa*) e o termo a que se refere (*aquela garota*) pertencem a frases entonacionais diferentes: a oração explicativa é uma frase entonacional independente da entoação da oração principal e “marcada na fala por mudança na tessitura”.

Nós modulamos as entoações instintivamente, e descrevê-las por palavras é difícil ou mesmo impossível; de modo que essa entoação independente da oração explicativa, a tal “mudança de tessitura”, é descrita nas abordagens mais simples como uma pausa entre a oração principal e a explicativa, pausa essa marcada na escrita por uma vírgula. Cito Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra na *Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo* (Lisboa, 2014, p. 812-13):

> Como sabemos, as ORAÇÕES SUBORDINADAS ADJETIVAS classificam-se em RESTITIVAS e EXPLICATIVAS.
>   As RESTRITIVAS, indispensáveis ao sentido da frase, ligam-se a um substantivo (ou pronome) antecedente sem pausa, razão por que dele não se separam, na escrita, por vírgula. Já as EXPLICATIVAS, denotadoras de uma qualidade acessória do antecedente — e, portanto, dispensáveis ao sentido essencial da frase —, separam-se dele por pausa, indicada na escrita por vírgula.

O [*Só Português*](https://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/sint/sint36.php) diz o mesmo:

> A oração subordinada adjetiva explicativa é separada da oração principal por uma pausa, que, na escrita, é representada pela vírgula.

Encontrei um artigo científico — [Erotilde Goreti Pezatti, “Da descrição ao ensino da oração adjetiva: a perspectiva dos livros didáticos de língua portuguesa”, *Lingüística*, Vol. 30(2), Diciembre 2014: 141-170](http://www.scielo.edu.uy/pdf/ling/v30n2/v30n2a07.pdf) — que elabora mais a questão. Diz a autora (p. 155-7) que a oração adjetiva explicativa tem “um contorno entonacional próprio, que independe do da oração principal” (p. 155), enquanto

> Diferentemente da explicativa, a oração adjetiva restritiva não tem um contorno entonacional próprio e consequentemente não apresenta uma ilocução. Em outras palavras, não constitui por si só um Ato Discursivo, ao contrário modifica o núcleo do sintagma nominal a que pertence e com o qual forma uma Frase Entanocional. [p. 156]

Um pouco mais à frente:

> A diferença na formulação das orações adjetivas é mapeada exclusivamente na representação fonológica. Conforme observa Câmara (inédito), a oração adjetiva explicativa, por apresentar um contorno entoacional próprio, constitui uma Frase Entoacional, claramente marcada na fala por mudança na tessitura, o que não se verifica na oração adjetiva restritiva. Essa diferença prosódica é então assinalada, na modalidade escrita, pelo uso de vírgulas, na oração adjetiva explicativa, e por sua ausência, na oração adjetiva restritiva.

Comment: O problema central reside em justamente a pausa não ser completamente confiável. Poderia dar alternativas, que não necessitem de pausa e que transmitam o mesmo significado, às frases, já que nem eu nem stafusa concebemos qualquer uma?

Comment: Eu creio que me perdi um bocado na discussão entre ti e o Stafusa."Pausa" é um bocado redutor: a frase com a oração explicativa é entoada de forma diferente da frase com oração restritiva, e é essa diferença de entoação que se usa para fazer a diferença entre uma e outra na fala. Mas a diferença mais fácil de descrever é a tal pausa. Acrescentei mais sobre isso.

Comment: "Não ser completamente confiável" Queres dizer que em conversa espontânea nós fazemos imensas pausas por causa de atrapalhações, hesitações, etc.? E também há o contrário: uma pessoa lê um texto tipo metralhadora, sem atentar ao sentido do que está a ler. Mas isso equivale a escrevermos um texto à pressa sem pontuação. Num discurso bem pronunciado, nós colocamos as pausas, inflexões de voz, etc. onde elas são precisas.

Comment: Sim, é o quero dizer. Todavia, muitas pessoas, mesmo escutando um 'discurso bem pronunciado', não conseguiriam perceber a distinção nitidamente apenas pela entoação — a qual pode ser muito mais facilmente errada do que a seleção de palavras. Ainda que gostaria de uma plausível estrutura substituta para a explicativa, que depende de tom e pausa, dou green-check.

Comment: @William, "gostaria de uma plausível estrutura substituta". Já tinhas pedido isso antes, e eu não tinha compreendido o que pedias. Vou pensar no assunto. Creio que em geral depende da intenção da explicativa. Enquanto a intenção da restritiva é clara--identificar a garota, ou aquilo de que se fala--a explicativa pode der intenções várias. É claro que poderias sempre dizer, "Adora aquela garota. E gostaria de acrescentar que ela é muito prestativa". Mas normalmente a explicativa não está lá só para adicionar uma informação avulsa qualquer; antes serve um propósito específico do falante.