# É correto usarmos duas preposições seguidas?

Tags: gramática, preposições

Ouço no rádio e na televisão, com relativa frequência, o uso de duas preposições seguidas conforme nos exemplos abaixo:

- Ela demonstrou grande respeito **para com** o presidente.
- A professora demonstra muito carinho **para com** os seus alunos.
- A gaivota passou voando **por sobre** a torre da igreja.
- Ronaldo chutou forte mas a bola passou **por sobre** a rede.

O uso de duas preposições seguidas fere alguma regra gramatical?  É aceito como correto?  Seria considerado pedante na língua falada informal?

Eu, pessoalmente, diria "pelo presidente", "pelos seus alunos", "sobre a torre" e "sobre a rede".

Comment: Relevante: [Locuções com duas preposições](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/locucoes-com-duas-preposicoes/33302) e [preposições juntas](http://sualingua.com.br/2009/05/11/preposicoes-juntas/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No [*link*](http://sualingua.com.br/2009/05/11/preposicoes-juntas/) informado pelo @stafusa no comentário, foi citado grandes obras de grandes escritores, todavia pode ser considerado como licença poética.

---

Em uma aula da professora [Giancarla Bombonato](https://www.escavador.com/sobre/5413302/giancarla-bombonato), ela afirma que não podemos usar duas preposições seguidas, já que a função dela é ligar dois termos, por exemplo:

```
┌─────────────────┬────────────────┐
│ Incorreto       │ Correto        │
├─────────────────┼────────────────┤
│ Perante ao Juiz │ Perante o Juiz │
├─────────────────┼────────────────┤
│ Contra à vida   │ Contra a Vida  │
└─────────────────┴────────────────┘
```

O professor [Sérgio Nogueira](http://g1.globo.com/educacao/blog/dicas-de-portugues/) partilha da mesma ideia. Em uma dúvida publicada na página [Dúvidas dos leitores](http://g1.globo.com/educacao/blog/dicas-de-portugues/post/235.html), um leitor fez a seguinte indagação:

> O técnico da seleção só falou **após ao** ou **após o** jogo?

Como resposta, obteve o seguinte:

> O técnico da seleção só falou após o jogo.
>   A presença da preposição **após** dispensa a preposição **a**. É bom lembrar que **ao** é a combinação da preposição **a** com o artigo definido **o**. *Não há necessidade de usarmos duas preposições juntas.* Outro exemplo errado é "estava perante ao juiz". O correto é dizer "perante o juiz".

Comment: Só é permitido "até a".
"Mais interessante ainda é a combinação de até + a, uma locução prepositiva usada com a intenção de aclarar o sentido da frase. ... Em frases como “o incêndio na plantação queimou tudo, até o portão”, abre-se a possibilidade de dupla interpretação: o fogo chegou até o portão, e aí parou (o até é visto como preposição), ou o fogo queimou tudo, inclusive o portão? Por esse motivo, costuma-se reforçar a preposição até com a preposição a: “o fogo queimou tudo, até ao portão”; dessa forma, fica eliminada a leitura do até como inclusive." (Prof. Moreno - Sua Língua)

Comment: @PaulodeTarsoOliveiraBastos Discordo, 'até ao portão' é redundante e incorreto, seria como dizer 'Nós fomos para ao Canadá.'. A eliminação da ambiguidade em língua escrita se dá por meio do uso da vírgula (com vírgula para o portão foi queimado, sem vírgula para o fogo parou no portão (ou simplesmente por 'até o portão' no início da frase)), e em língua falada por pausa + intonação. Vide resposta de Jacinto em: https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/ambiguidade-na-l%C3%ADngua-falada-entre-uma-restritiva-e-uma-explicativa

Comment: @WillianLio, Acredito que as duas formas estão corretas. No Brasil é raro ouvir "até ao" posto que é comum em Portugal. [http://www.aulete.com.br/at%C3%A9][www.lexico.pt/ate/] [http://sualingua.com.br/2009/05/11/preposicoes-juntas/] [www.recantodasletras.com.br/gramatica/3399649] [http://www.linguativa.com.br/laphp/conteudo/tipoDicionario.php?categoriaPrograma=2024&chamada=37448] [www.infopedia.pt/$ate-as-dez-horas-ou-ate-as-dez-horas?uri=vocabulario/até]

Comment: Resposta muito enviesada. *Para com* e outras duplas de preposições seguidas vêm em vários dicionários e gramáticas sem qualquer advertência: não vêm indicadas como sendo erro ou licença poética. Dizer que que pode ser licença poética porque são citações de grandes autores não faz sentido. Gramáticas e Cláudio Moreno usam citações de grandes autores para ilustrar português correto, exemplos a seguir. Os autores que citas, se afirmam que duas preposições seguidas são sempre um erro, é a opinião deles contra dicionários e gramáticos. >>

Comment: E o Sérgio Nogueira diz apenas que *para com* é **em geral** desnecessário; não diz que seja um erro ou sequer que seja sempre desnecessário

Answer (score 3):

### Correção e aceitação

A língua padrão aceita varias duplas de preposições seguidas. No dicionário Houaiss e no dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa encontramos ***para com*** (’com relação a’), ***por entre*** (’pelo meio de’) e ***até a*** (esta é especial, de regra em Portugal mas não no Brasil; para os interessados, reproduzo no fim a explicação muito completa do Houaiss).

Estes pares não são os únicos. Evanildo Bechara explica na [*Moderna Gramática Portuguesa*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=kA5LywXfV-kC&pg=PT247&dq=%22raro%20duas%20preposi%C3%A7%C3%B5es%20se%20juntam%20para%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiYoerVz5jrAhUrAGMBHXkIAccQ6AEwAHoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22raro%20duas%20preposi%C3%A7%C3%B5es%20se%20juntam%20para%22&f=false):

> **Acúmulo de preposições** — Não raro duas preposições se juntam para dar maior efeito expressivo às ideias, guardando cada uma seu sentido primitivo:
>
> > Andou *por sobre* o mar.
>
> Estes acúmulos de preposições não constituem uma locução prepositiva porque valem por duas preposições distintas [as locuções prepositivas, como *até a, depois de, graças a*, valem por uma única preposição]. Combinam-se com maior frequência as preposições: *de, para* e *por* com *entre, sob* e *sobre*.
>
> > “De uma vez olhou *por entre* duas portadas mal fechadas para o interior de outra sala…” [Camilo de Castelo Branco]
> >
> > “Os deputados oposicionistas conjuravam-no a não levantar mão *de sobre* os projetos depredadores” [Camilo de Castelo Branco]

A *Gramática do Português* da Gulbenkian (Lisboa 2013, tomo II, p. 1505; explicação reproduzida [neste artigo do Ciberduúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/locucoes-com-duas-preposicoes/33302)) explica que nestes casos temos um sintagma preposicional dentro de outro sintagma preposicional. Por exemplo, em *ele olhou por um canudo* temos o sintagma preposicional *por um canudo*, composto pela preposição *por* e pelo seu complemento *um canudo*. Ora, uma preposição pode ter por  complemento outro sintagma preposicional: em ver de ele olhar por um canudo, pode olhar *por* [*entre as portadas mal fechadas*], em que *por* e *entre* mantêm os seus significados primitivos.

Isto dá-nos possibilidades de combinar várias preposições. Por exemplo, a chegada do avião pode estar prevista *para* [*as cinco da tarde*]; mas também pode ser que

> A chegada do avião está prevista  ***para entre** as cinco e as seis da tarde*.

Portanto é verdade, como diz uma professora referida na resposta do Valdeir, que a função da preposição é ligar dois termos. Mas nada impede que, em alguns casos, o termo à direita comece ele mesmo com outra preposição.

### É considerado pedante na língua falada informal?

A meu ver, depende. Parece-me que os últimos dois exemplos acima — *olhou por entre as portadas mal fechadas* e *prevista para entre as seis e as cinco* — são lógicos, relativamente corriqueiros, e não destoariam numa conversa informal.

Quanto aos teus exemplos, se a junção de duas preposições visa, nas palavras do Evanildo Bechara, “maior efeito expressivo”, eu não vejo qual seja o efeito expressivo em “a bola passou por sobre a rede” ou “voando sobre a torre da igreja”; tal como tu, eu diria *sobre* ou *por cima de*. Mas o *por sobre* tem tradições literárias, e alguns (não todos) dos [exemplos citados pelo Cláudio Moreno](https://sualingua.com.br/2009/05/11/preposicoes-juntas/) já me parecem mais convincentes. Gosto de “o som mole dos chinelos que se aproximam ‘por sobre o tapete’”. A preposição *por* dá a ideia do movimento *sobre* o tapete; fá-lo de forma mais sugestiva do que se disséssemos simplesmente *chinelos que se aproximavam sobre o tapete*. Pergunto-me se alguns *por sobre*, como na bola passando por sobre a rede, não é simplesmente o desejo de variar por variar ou de “falar bonito” — temos um comentador de futebol em Portugal que em vez de dizer que um jogador é grande, diz que ele tem dados antropométricos notáveis!

***Para com***. Nos teus exemplos, o *para com* poderia perfeitamente ser substituído por *pelo* ou *pelos*, mas também não me choca. Noutros casos, porém, *para com* parece-me talvez a melhor opção:

> Gostei da tua atitude para com a Joana

Aqui, *pela* não serviria. *Atitude com a Joana* talvez escape, mas não transmite tão claramente a ideia que a Joana é o alvo da atitude. Depois teríamos *atitude em relação à Joana*, que não melhora em concisão e seria talvez um pouco mais vago.

É claro que existindo *para com* para estas situações, em que é mais adequado que as alternativas, ele fica também disponível para outras situações em que poderá não trazer grande vantagem, como nos teu exemplos. A questão é que este *para com* já cá anda há séculos. O Camões já o usou, numa carta a uma amigo; não foi nenhum artifício para cumprir a métrica ou a rima: “Nenhuma cousa me enche tanto as medidas para com estes que vivem a mor bonança, do que ela [a morte]” ([Obras Completas de Luís de Camões](https://books.google.pt/books?id=A64OAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA1-PA220&dq=%22me%20enche%20tanto%20as%20medidas%20para%20com%20estes%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiMhfCmjZnrAhVCr3EKHWjVA-4Q6AEwAHoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22me%20enche%20tanto%20as%20medidas%20para%20com%20estes%22&f=false)). Basta uma busca no Google Boks para ver que este *para com* é depois muito usado ao longo dos séculos. E o uso é o tribunal de última instância em matéria de correção.

### Até a

*Até a* é uma verdadeira locução prepositiva, porque as duas preposições valem por uma só, em vez de manterem cada uma os seus sentidos primitivos. Ou melhor, *até* mantém, e *a* serve apenas de ligação. O Houaiss explica:

> **até** […] GRAMÁTICA/USO **a)** como advérbio, Portugal e Brasil (no sentido de ’inclusive’) empregam-no do mesmo modo (*até tu, Brutus?, gosto até de morangos ácidos*) **b)** como preposição, em Portugal, usa-se associado à preposição *a* (*ir até ao parque* e não *ir até o parque; caminhar até à igreja* e não *caminhar até a igreja*), enquanto no Brasil é indiferentemente correto associá-lo ou não à outra preposição, embora por vezes se imponha tal escolha para evitar a ambiguidade ente os uso da preposição e o uso do advérbio (numa frase sem a preposição *a* do tipo *estudei até a quinta lição*, o *até* pode ser entendido, no Brasil, como preposição ’até ao limite da quinta lição’ ou como advérbio ’até mesmo a quinta lição;* historicamente, até ao sXVII, usou-se na língua apenas *até;* nesse mesmo século começou a surgir *até a*, com o artigo feminino (*até à, até às*), e posteriormente com o artigo masculino (*até ao, até aos*); grandes escritores dos sXIX e XX alternaram o emprego do *até* preposicionado com o *até* sem preposição, por vezes na mesma obra (Machado de Assis, por exemplo)

Note-se que a preposição *a* liga *até* ao artigo: *vou até ao Brasil, até à China* mas, como Portugal não leva artigo, simplesmente *até Portugal*. Do mesmo modo, *espero até ao meio-dia* mas *espero até sábado/até ele chegar*.

Answer (score 1):

É correto o uso de "para com" e tem significado de "com relação a" ou "em relação a".

Não há problema algum!

Também "por sobre", "por sob", "até a" e aquela que, *dentre* todas, é a mais comum: "dentre" (de+entre).

Comment: Segundo quem? A resposta seria mais forte se incluisse citações de casos de uso ou de regras gramaticais.